# Spring REST service WAS7 Exception on startup

Tags: spring, exception, rest, websphere-7

I am trying to deploy a REST Service, developed with Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE, as war-file on WAS 7.0.0.17. On Startup i get the following Exception and the Service wont return a result (obviously):

```
[8/9/11 13:26:44:592 CEST] 00000013 extension     E com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor createServletWrapper Error occured while preparing the servlet for initialization.
                             javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:1809)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor.createServletWrapper(WebExtensionProcessor.java:98)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:1037)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:958)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeTargetMappings(WebApp.java:637)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:435)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:731)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:616)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:610)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:726)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2048)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:441)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$300(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:951)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'standorteDS' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/rest-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/springframework/expression/spel/support/StandardEvaluationContext.setBeanResolver(Lorg/springframework/expression/BeanResolver;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:192)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1707)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:380)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:299)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/springframework/expression/spel/support/StandardEvaluationContext.setBeanResolver(Lorg/springframework/expression/BeanResolver;)V
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    ... 33 more
```

I developed the application on a locally installed Tomcat Server. On that platform it was running without faults.

My rest-context.xml looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="standorteDS" class="mobile.standorte.ds.StandorteDS">
    <property name="ds" ref="datasource" />
</bean>

<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/my_datasource" />
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false" />
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</bean>
```

And my rest-servlet.xml looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- To enable @RequestMapping process on type level and method level -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>mobile.standorte.bean.Standort</value>
            <value>mobile.standorte.bean.StandorteList</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="standorte" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
    <constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"/>
            <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
        </map>
    </property>

    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="standorteController" class="mobile.standorte.controller.StandorteController">
    <property name="standorteDS" ref="standorteDS" />
    <property name="jaxb2Mashaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
</bean>
```

and finally the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_1189606987655" version="2.5">

<display-name>Standorte Service Mobile</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- The context params that read by ContextLoaderListener  -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/rest-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- This listener will load other application context file in addition to springweb-servlet.xml -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/StandorteService/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The datasource is configured in the Application Server and the class with the property ds is also deployed.

I cant find any answers why the Service wont start. Thanks for any hints how to solve the problem.

Comment: Wanted to add that the application is configured with Classloader "Parent last" so that websphere loads configuration from application first.

Comment: I found the problem. A dependency to Release 3.0.0.Release did add the lib springframework-expression in Version 3.0.0.Release in addition to the web-mvc 3.0.5.Release. Strangly Tomcat did load the right one, websphere chose the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by this line I would say there where is a version mismatch or jar missing check and make sure spring-expression.jar is there.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'standorteDS' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/rest-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/springframework/expression/spel/support/StandardEvaluationContext.setBeanResolver(Lorg/springframework/expression/BeanResolver;)
```

Comment: hi, of course i checked it and the lib is in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the installed war file "spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"

Comment: Okay, I'm not familiar with WebSphere but in jBoss you can some times have classes not being detected because the application server contains older versions of the same file. So I would check any library folders in WebSphere for spring jar. Though AFAIK war libraries should be given precedence over any common or shared ones.